# Revisiting Events in Dune House Secrets?

Tags: dune-house-secrets

In [Dune: House Secrets](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/329713/dune-house-secrets) we chose to move on to another event without paying the cost to flip the card over to the other side. At the end of the chapter we had plenty of xp left for the chapter, so we wanted to know if we could revisit cards we had previously visited and try the risk so that we don't waste it?